# The issue in Google Sign-In for Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-docs

brother, I'm now integrating Google login functionality into my app in accordance with Google Docs.

When I follow the instructions in the document, I click on the button **Configure a project** to **Configure a Google API Console project** and I filled out all the information that I needed to fill out, including the platform, package name, and the value of `sha-1`, but when I clicked on the create button in popWindow again, I got the message *Something went wrong. Please try again.* I have tried numerous times. All of these are the results. Can someone help me to see what causes me? Thanks a lot!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check if you have a project with same package name and fingerprint.

Comment: I tried again to create a new package name and use the same sha-1 value but got the same error.Hi,bro, where did I go wrong.

Comment: I did not follow Google's documentation first configure a project and then Get my backend server's client ID, but I first Get my backend server's client ID and Next to Configure a project, it may be caused by the order of my mistakes?
I'll change the order of operation tomorrow and try again.

Answer (score 7):

Please check if you have already added your project in **firebase**. If you have, do not add the project again in **google developer console**; it's kind of added to developer console by default. This is how I solved the issue in my case.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sometime, I fake this problem too

My case is:
1) I create project new from [Google console](https://console.cloud.google.com) **first**
2) I start [Configure a project for Google Sign](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_console_name_project) for the project created in step 1
3) Enter correct SHA1 and package_name
4) Error "Something when wrong and please try again"

I tested 5 times for 5 new projects and this problem always happened

**THEN I SOLVED** it by a trick like
1) I **don't** create new project in [Google console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
2) When [Configure a project for Google Sign](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_console_name_project), I create new project here (don't use project name which already used before even you have shutdown it)

[image]
3) Enter correct SHA1 and package_name
4) It will working with no error

Tested it 3 times for 2 different emails and it working.
Hope it help

Comment: That helped me. Thank you for taking the time to test

Answer (score 0):

None of the following solutions worked for me. What I did was look into my Google API Console > Credentials. Then I noticed that while from the documentation I picked my "Type" to be "android", on the console it appeared as "Web".

When I deleted the credential and re-entered the details it worked like a charm. So if none of the solutions work, try deleting all credentials in the API console and try another time.